# Define "current time" when starting Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that changes behavior based on the time of the day, and I'd like to be able to just spin up the server and test how it works at different times.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just pass in the time as an argument when I run `rails s`, like `rails s TIME=2014-02-26 22:06:11 -0500`.

Comment: Write tests for your app using something like timecop (https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop), which will stub out the app's time with a time you specify. Don't actually modify the time in your app.

Comment: @sevenseacat Thanks -- I'd totally forgotten about timecop. What I'm interested in now, though, is running it live at a particular time in development, not just testing. Still, this will come in handy for testing this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually read environment variables from within rails (actually Ruby). This is how to do it:

```
require 'date'
$startup_time = DateTime.parse(ENV['STARTUP_TIME']) rescue DateTime.now
puts "Server started at: #{$startup_time}"
```

You'd call this code placed in `pull_time.rb` like this:

```
STARTUP_TIME="2014-02-26 22:06:11 -0500" ruby pull_time.rb
```

In order to have this global variable work in Rails, you want to add it to an initializer.

So put the code above in `config/initializers/set_startup_time.rb`

You can now access `$startup_time` anywhere in your code. Just pass `STARTUP_TIME` as an environment variable to rails.

```
STARTUP_TIME=2014-02-26 22:06:11 -0500 rails s
```

Answer (score 1):

In config/locales/application.rb you can set the timezone before running rails s.

```
config.time_zone = 'Alaska'
```

If you're running OS X, you can also set the system time in the terminal before running rails s.

```
date 022611002013
```

The format is [month][day][hh][mm][year], so the above is 11:00 February 26, 2013. You can change your system time back to the current time in the terminal or Date and Time preferences panel.

Comment: Great to know! Though I would be a little bit afraid to mess with the OSX system time too much -- seems ripe for disaster with other apps or projects.

Answer (score 1):

Rails server uses time of the hosting machine. So if you are running on local machine then changing the time of the local operating system will also have effect on your rails server

If it's hosted on another server then you have to change that server's time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try changing the time of your server. That can play real havoc with cron jobs or other time-based services.

Instead, have you tried defining the starting time as a specific value in your code then running the server? Then set it to the next time you need, and run the server again?

```
Time.new(2013, 12, 31, 12, 59, 59) # => 2013-12-31 12:59:59 -0700
```

You could also use the time as an integer, using the number of seconds that represent the time you want the server to think it is. Pass that in as an `ENV` hash element, then check to see if it's defined. If it is, define the time based on that value, otherwise don't define the `ENV` value and the server will run as normal:

```
ENV['SERVER_TIME'] = '1388519999'
server_time = ENV['SERVER_TIME'] ? Time.at(ENV['SERVER_TIME'].to_i) : Time.now
server_time # => 2013-12-31 12:59:59 -0700
```

Then, when you need to test the server, you could write a little shell script that sets that value and runs `rails s`, test the server then quit it, and rerun the shell script with a different value.

Comment: I think if you're testing time changes you'd want the cron jobs to be executed based on the "testing time"?

Answer (score 0):

Rails server determine time from the hosting machine

So changing the system's time would do the trick

**EDIT:**
As 'sevenseacat' said in comment

you can also use gem [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to test your application without changing system's time.

Comment: if you would like to set timezone then,
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change Rails' internal timezone by adding `config.time_zone = 'Pacific'` to  `application.rb`.

If you're deploying to Heroku, you can do the same slightly differently: `heroku config:add TZ="Europe/Athens"`.

However, the downside is that neither of these commands allows you to define a specific **time** for the app (just the timezone, so you get the current time in another timezone), nor can you run these from command-line when starting your local Rails server.